# Conditional logic for ON DELETE foreign key reference

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I want to be able to perform some logic for foreign key ON DELETE constraints. Depending on the logic, I will either want to CASCADE or RESTRICT.

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE teams (
  team_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE documents (
  document_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY
  user_id uuid REFERENCES users ON DELETE /*do logic here*/,
  team_id uuid REFERENCES teams ON DELETE /*do logic here*/,
  content text
);
```

In my (very basic) tables a `document` can be owned by a `user` and/or a `team`.

Regarding `documents`, if someone deletes a user of a document and the document's `team_id` IS NULL then CASCADE the deletion to the document (or vice-versa with user_id and team_id).

Otherwise, if someone deletes a user of a document and the document's `team_id` IS NOT NULL then RESTRICT the deletion of the user (or vice-versa with user_id and team_id).

I didn't see any way of accomplishing this in the documentation. Will I need to do this logic in my server code instead of in the database? I wanted extra layers of data integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's quite possible but not directly. You need a trigger. First set the foreign key to be RESTRICT

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
  document_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id uuid REFERENCES users ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  team_id uuid REFERENCES teams ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  content text
);
```

Then create the trigger function and the trigger for the user table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_delete()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM documents WHERE team_id IS NULL and user_id = OLD.user_id;
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER user_delete_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON users FOR EACH ROW     EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_delete();
```

Then do the same for the team table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION team_delete()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM documents WHERE user_id IS NULL and team_id = OLD.team_id;
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER team_delete_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON users FOR EACH ROW     EXECUTE PROCEDURE team_delete();
```

and this I believe does exactly what you are looking for.